# SQL Server Database Mail is sending blank messages when I give it an HTML body

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-mail

I'm trying to use the SQL Server Management Studio Database Mail to send automated HTML-formatted emails. It works fine when I give it a plain-text body, but as soon as I change it to HTML, the messages are blank. They still send with the proper subject and everything else, but the body isn't there.

Here's the relevant bit of code:

```
 DECLARE @msg varchar(8000); --body of the message in html.
 DECLARE @recipient_emails varchar(50); --List of email addresses for everyone who needs to receive this message.
 DECLARE @subject_line varchar(100); --Subject line for the email.
 DECLARE @num_of_msgs int; --Since some updates need to trigger multiple different emails, this is used to determine how many emails will be sent.
 DECLARE @creator varchar(10); --Creator of the opportunity in CRM.
 DECLARE @account_id int; --Account number for customer.
 DECLARE @customer varchar(50); --Customer from whom the opportunity came.
 DECLARE @opty_type varchar(30); --Type of opportunity.
 DECLARE @opty_desc varchar(40); --Description of opportunity.
 DECLARE @date_created datetime; --Datetime when opportunity was created.
 DECLARE @notes varchar(500); --Notes about opportunity.

 SELECT
 @creator = CREATOR,
 @account_id = ACCT_ID,
 @opty_type = OPTY_TYPE_ID,
 @opty_desc = DESCRIPTION,
 @date_created = OPEN_DATE,
 @notes = COMMENTS
 FROM V_OPPORTUNITY
 WHERE ID = @opty_id;

 --Uses a CASE statement to determine recipient emails based on what activity has just been completed.
 SET @recipient_emails =
 CASE @description
  WHEN 'Create Opportunity in CRM' THEN 'nate.lovell@aggiemail.usu.edu'
  WHEN 'Request NDA' THEN 'Email 2'
  WHEN 'Receive Formula' THEN 'Email 3'
  WHEN 'Receive Product Specs-general lbl claim & pkg spec' THEN 'Email 4'
  WHEN 'Issue Ballpark Quote' THEN 'Email 5'
  WHEN 'Credit Check' THEN 'Email 6'
  ELSE ''
 END;

 --Uses a CASE statement to determine HTML message based on what activity has just been completed.
 SET @msg = 
 CASE @description
  WHEN 'Create Opportunity in CRM' THEN '<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DLI NEW CRM OPTY EMAIL</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #61FF51;
}
div#PAGECENTER {
   width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto
 }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="2" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace; font-weight: bold; font-size: 36px;"><p><!--<img src="/Images/DESLABLGtag3d.png" width="52" height="53" alt=""/>--><span style="font-size: 24px"> NEW OPTY CREATED IN CRM</span></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="15%" height="40" align="right" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold">CREATED BY</td>
      <td width="35%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+@creator+'</td>
      <td width="15%" height="40" align="right" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold">CUSTOMER</td>
      <td width="35%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">SQL HERE</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="15%" height="40" align="right" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold">OPTY TYPE</td>
      <td width="35%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+@opty_type+'</td>
      <td width="15%" height="40" align="right" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold">DESCRIPTION</td>
      <td width="35%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+@opty_desc+'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="15%" height="40" align="right" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold">DATE CREATED</td>
      <td width="35%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+CAST(@date_created AS varchar(20))+'</span></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="15%" height="40" align="right" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold">NOTES</td>
      <td height="40" colspan="3" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace">'+ISNULL(@notes,'')+'</span></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="PAGECENTER"></div>
</body>
</html>'

  WHEN 'Request NDA' THEN 'Msg 2'
  WHEN 'Receive Formula' THEN 'Msg 3'
  WHEN 'Receive Product Specs-general lbl claim & pkg spec' THEN 'Msg 4'
  WHEN 'Issue Ballpark Quote' THEN 'Msg 5'
  WHEN 'Credit Check' THEN 'Msg 6'
  ELSE 'DEFAULT MSG'
 END;

 --Uses a CASE statement to determine subject line based on what activity has just been completed.
 SET @subject_line = 
 CASE @description
  WHEN 'Create Opportunity in CRM' THEN 'Subject 1'
  WHEN 'Request NDA' THEN 'Subject 2'
  WHEN 'Receive Formula' THEN 'Subject 3'
  WHEN 'Receive Product Specs-general lbl claim & pkg spec' THEN 'Subject 4'
  WHEN 'Issue Ballpark Quote' THEN 'Subject 5'
  WHEN 'Credit Check' THEN 'Subject 6'
  ELSE 'DEFAULT SUBJECT'
 END;

 --Uses a CASE statement to determine number of messages based on what activity has just been completed.
 SET @num_of_msgs = 
 CASE @description
  WHEN 'Create Opportunity in CRM' THEN 2
  WHEN 'Request NDA' THEN 1
  WHEN 'Receive Formula' THEN 1
  WHEN 'Receive Product Specs-general lbl claim & pkg spec' THEN 1
  WHEN 'Issue Ballpark Quote' THEN 1
  WHEN 'Credit Check' THEN 1
  ELSE 1
 END;

 --Sends an email.
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = @recipient_emails, @body = @msg, @body_format = 'HTML',  @subject = @subject_line, @profile_name = 'SQLProfile';
```

NOTES: The only case I'm worried about getting to work right now is the one for 'Create Opportunity in CRM'. Also, several variables used here are declared and/or set earlier in the code, like @opty_id and @description.

Comment: If you `select @msg` before the send call, you see what you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: Put an `else` in all the `case` statements, so you can see if there are any matches.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks. But still nothing.

Comment: Like Gordon said, a null value in a variable can produce a blank email. I used ISNULL(@variable, ' ') to solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause for failure is that there is no match to the `case` expressions. You should have an `else` clause in all the `CASE` expressions to be sure they are processed as you intend.

A *very close* second is that one or more of the columns used for constructing `@msg` are `NULL`. This will result in the entire value being `NULL`.

For instance, if there are no comments, then `@Notes` might be `NULL` and the whole `@msg` will end up being `NULL`.

You should add:

```
SELECT @creator, @account_id, @opty_type, @opty_desc, @date_created, @notes
```

To be sure none of these values are `NULL`.

You can protect against `NULL` values when `@msg` is defined by using `COALESCE()`.